# iOS & Google Analytics - How many events to send?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have an app that allows its users to make YES/NO decisions about a huge number of items.
I want to use google analytics to track those decisions.

Lets say a user's decision takes one second.
When i send data to google every 120 seconds thats 120 Events each time. Do I have to worry about this in terms of app speed, bandwidth, or google analytics policy?

Is there a better way to achieve something similar?

Comment: I dont think speed or bandwidth are going to be problems, but if the app becomes popular you might hit the data limit in analytics which is at 10 Million "Hits" per month. A hit in this case would be an event